# Como testar se um EditText está vazio?

Tags: java, android, edittext

Gostaria de saber como eu faço para testar se um *EditText* está vazio ou preenchido no Android.
Por exemplo, quero fazer um app que vai realizar um cadastro, mas há campos que não podem ficar vazios então, eu gostaria de saber como fazer esse teste, no caso, se houvesse um campo vazio, ele retornaria uma mensagem dizendo que os campos não podem ficar em branco.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if(meuEditText.getText().length() == 0){//como o tamanho é zero é nulla aresposta

       meuEditText.setError("Campo vazio");

}else if (meuEditText.getText().length() < 5){

      meuEditText.setError("Minimo 5 letras");

}
```

Da próxima poste algum código, poste sua tentativa,

Comment: `getText()` nunca retorna `null`.

Comment: compare assim clength() == 0** que vc vai sazer que nao tem nada preenchido, que é null do mesmo jeito. tente colocar um **meuEditText.getText().toString()**. Se o tamanho for zero é nullo, nao tem nada preenchido

Comment: Daí sim, então edite sua resposta.

Comment: @Piovezan o cara quer a resposta, nao posta nenhum codigo, ai vou ajudar, posto algo pra ele pensar um pouco, e vc me diminui, vai entender. :(

Comment: Apenas pedi para você corrigir sua resposta, que estava incorreta (no Java string vazia é diferente de null) e retornei o voto a favor da sua resposta, nada mais. Se a pessoa que perguntou não forneceu detalhes, peça esses detalhes nos comentários antes de tentar uma resposta.

Answer (score 4):

```
if (meuEditText.getText().toString().trim().equals("")) {
    ....
```

Note que `getText()` nunca retorna o valor `null`, na pior das hipóteses ele retorna vazio, ou seja, "".

Opcionalmente você pode testar `length() == 0` ou `isEmpty()` (este último caso a partir da API nível 9).

Answer (score 2):

Dá para você verificar assim dessa forma criando a seguinte função, que verificará se possui espaço em branco e se o tamanho da string é menor que 1.

```
private boolean isEmpty(EditText etText) {
        String text = etText.getText().toString().trim();
        if (text.length()<1)
            return true;
        return false;
}
```

Respondi nesta questão [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/146098/35406) também.

Comment: Acho que o isEmpty() é o método mais interessante. Valeu pela dica!

Answer (score 2):

Voce pode testar desta forma, com o `equals("")`

Ex:

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (edtAltura.getText().toString().equals("")) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Campo Altura está vazio!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            edtAltura.requestFocus();
        } else if (edtPeso.getText().toString().equals("")) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Campo Altura está vazio!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            edtPeso.requestFocus();
        } else {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(editText.getText().toString().matches("")){
 .....
}
```

O método `matches()` diz se a sequência de caracteres passada corresponde ou não a determinada expressão regular.

Comment: Coloque algum comentário pra explicar o seu código. Dar a solução sem explicar, não acho uma boa idéia

Answer (score 0):

A forma mais eficiente é utilizando a classe `TextUtils` da seguinte forma:

```
TextUtils.isEmpty(nome_editText.getText().toString());
```

ele verifica por exemplo se foi inserido 2 espaços em branco. O que nao ocorre se você pegar o tamanho da string inserida no `editText`.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o seguinte:

```
if (meuEditText.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
   //faça tal...
}
```