# Verificar se EditText está vazio

Tags: java, android

Olá pessoal estou fazendo um aplicativo no *android studio* mas não sei exatamente como verificar se os campos do texto estão vazio, tentei a seguinte solução no código abaixo :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText edt1,edt2;
TextView tv3;
float n1 = 0.70f;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    edt1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    edt2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    tv3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);

}


public void calcular(View v){

    double valor1 = Double.parseDouble(edt1.getText().toString());
    double valor2 = Double.parseDouble(edt2.getText().toString());


    double resultado1 = valor1 * n1;

    if (edt1.getText().toString().equals("")){
       tv3.setText("Campo vazio");
    }

    if (edt2.getText().toString().equals("")){
       tv3.setText("Campo vazio");
    }

    if (resultado1 < valor2) {
        tv3.setText("Vale a pena Abastecer com Gasolina");
    }


    else {
        tv3.setText("Vale a pena Abastecer com Alcool");
    }


    }

}
```

Mais ao clicar no executar com os campos vazios recebo o seguinte erro:

```
08-08 15:21:53.288 25012-25012/com.dolardehoje.formulario W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41a19930)
08-08 15:21:53.298 25012-25012/com.dolardehoje.formulario E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4380)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18094)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5279)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4380) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18094) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5279) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
     Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: ""
        at java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal(StringToReal.java:63)
        at java.lang.StringToReal.parseDouble(StringToReal.java:248)
        at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:295)
        at com.dolardehoje.formulario.MainActivity.calcular(MainActivity.java:38)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4380) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18094) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5279) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como testar se um EditText está vazio?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/86544/como-testar-se-um-edittext-est%c3%a1-vazio)

Comment: Tente da seguinte forma: **TextUtils.isEmpty(edt1.getText().toString())**

Comment: Veja [Como considerar um EditText vazio como “0”](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/89367/2541)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O erro acontece por que você está a tentar obter um *Double* de uma String que é nula ou não tem um valor convertível.

Altere o código de forma a que seja feita a validação dos *EditText* antes de obter os valores em *Double*

```
public void calcular(View v){

    if (edt1.getText().toString().trim().equals("") ||
        edt2.getText().toString().trim().equals("")){

       Toast.makeText(this, "Valores incorretos",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }else{
        double valor1 = Double.parseDouble(edt1.getText().toString());
        double valor2 = Double.parseDouble(edt2.getText().toString());

        double resultado1 = valor1 * n1;

        if (resultado1 < valor2) {
            tv3.setText("Vale a pena Abastecer com Gasolina");
        }
        else {
            tv3.setText("Vale a pena Abastecer com Alcool");
        }
    }
}
```

Para garantir que o usuário só introduz valores válidos(números) acrescente os seguintes atributos ao *EditText* **edt1** e **edt2**

```
android:text="0" 
android:inputType="numberDecimal"
```

Comment: consegui usando a sua solução, obrigado!

Answer (score 3):

Se o que você quer é apenas verificar se o campo esta vazio tente usar a seguinte linha:

```
if(edt1.getText().toString().equals("")){
   //Colocar o que vc quer que aconteça caso esteja vazio.
}
```

ou entao:

```
if(!edt1.getText().toString().equals("")){
   //Colocar o que vc quer que aconteça caso não esteja vazio.
}
```

basicamente estou escolhendo o campo e pegando oq tem nele. E com o .equal("") estou comparando ele com um campo vazio.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Mesmo com isso da erro quando clico pra executar e o app da erro

Comment: Edite a sua pergunta e poste o erro q esta dando.

Comment: editei com o codigo atualizado

Comment: Edita novamente e coloca o erro apresentado.

Comment: O erro é o seguinte "sua aplicação parou"

Comment: Eu estou flando do "LOG" q é apresentado no "Android Monitor" na parte inferior do android studio.

Comment: adicionei o log do erro

Answer (score 1):

"thread exiting with uncaught exception"

declare valor1 e valor2 global e usa isso aqui :

```
try
{
    valor1 = Double.parseDouble(edt1.getText().toString());
    valor2 = Double.parseDouble(edt2.getText().toString());
} 
catch(NumberFormatException e)
{
    tv3.setText("Valor Invalido");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Baseado no que o ramaral fez, pois esta correto, eu apenas mudaria poucos pontos e acrecentaria algumas linha para o codigo ficar mais completo.

```
public void calcular(View v){

   if (edt1.getText().toString().trim().equals("") &&
       edt2.getText().toString().trim().equals("")){

       Toast.makeText(this, "Os dois campos estao vazios!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

   }else if(edt1.getText().toString().trim().equals("")){

       Toast.makeText(this, "O primeiro campo esta vazio",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

   }else if(edt2.getText().toString().trim().equals("")){

       Toast.makeText(this, "O segundo campo esta vazio",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

   }else{

       double valor1 = Double.parseDouble(edt1.getText().toString());
       double valor2 = Double.parseDouble(edt2.getText().toString());

       double resultado1 = valor1 * n1;

       if (resultado1 < valor2) {
           tv3.setText("Vale a pena Abastecer com Gasolina");

       }else {
           tv3.setText("Vale a pena Abastecer com Alcool");
       }
   }
}
```

Sei q são poucas as mudanças, Porem espero poder ter ajudado

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer assim:

```
if (edt1.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {

   //Informar que o campo 1 está vazio.

}
```

Comment: Se tiver um espaço em branco, não vai validar.

Answer (score 0):

Dá para você verificar assim dessa forma criando a seguinte função, que verificará se possui espaço em branco e se o tamanho da string é menor que 1.

```
private boolean isEmpty(EditText etText) {
        String text = etText.getText().toString().trim();
        if (text.length()<1)
            return true;
        return false;
}
```