# Como pegar um valor inteiro do EditText

Tags: java, android

Estou tendo problema no método `validar()` onde eu quero pegar um valor inteiro do `EditText` para poder comparar um resultado no `if`. Eu já tentei fazer um casting mas não suporta o cast de um widget para um inteiro. Alguém poderia me ajudar?

```
package br.com.irbs.desafiomatematica;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Random;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public int randomizarNumero(){
        Random random = new Random();

        int numeroRandomico = random.nextInt(100);

        return numeroRandomico;
    }

    public int randomizarNumeros(){
        TextView n1 = findViewById(R.id.numero1);
        TextView n2 = findViewById(R.id.numero2);
        TextView operador = findViewById(R.id.operador);

        int numeroRandomico1 = randomizarNumero();
        int numeroRandomico2 = randomizarNumero();
        int resultado = numeroRandomico1 + numeroRandomico2;

        n1.setText("" + numeroRandomico1);
        n2.setText("" + numeroRandomico2);
        operador.setText("+");

        return resultado;

    }

    public int randomizarNumeros(View view){
        TextView n1 = findViewById(R.id.numero1);
        TextView n2 = findViewById(R.id.numero2);
        TextView operador = findViewById(R.id.operador);

        int numeroRandomico1 = randomizarNumero();
        int numeroRandomico2 = randomizarNumero();
        int resultado = numeroRandomico1 + numeroRandomico2;

        n1.setText("" + numeroRandomico1);
        n2.setText("" + numeroRandomico2);
        operador.setText("+");

        return resultado;
    }

    public void validar(){
        EditText resultado = findViewById(R.id.resultadoUsuario);
        int conta = randomizarNumeros();

        if (resultado == conta) {

        }


    }

}
```

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Verificar se EditText está vazio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/146042/verificar-se-edittext-est%c3%a1-vazio)

Comment: Apesar do título ser diferente, a [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/146094/100416) aceita possui uma conversão para Double. Você não está pegando o texto da `EditText`, dá uma lida na resposta e ficará mais claro

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar dessa maneira:

```
int result = Integer.valueOf(seu_edit_text);
```

Assim converte o valor do EditText para numérico inteiro, porém é bom definir no EditText para ele aceitar somente números, se não irá causar Exceptions se alguém digitar alguma letra ou caractere especial.