# Aplicação fecha quando tento logar sem preencher os campos

Tags: java, android

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação, e não estou conseguindo fazer com que a tela de login verifique se os campos estão sendo preenchidos ou se estão com usuário e senha errados. Segue o código do login.

Ele loga normal, o problema mesmo é quando eu clico em logar sem preencher os campos ou com usuário ou senha errados.

```
package com.rafaeljacinto.newtest4;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class Telalogin extends AppCompatActivity {



    EditText name, password;
    Button login;
    String Name, Password;
    Context ctx=this;
    String codAlu =null, nomeAlu = null,  emailAlu = null, foneAlu = null;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_telalogin);

        name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        login = (Button)findViewById(R.id.login);
        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Name = name.getText().toString();
                Password = password.getText().toString();
                BackGround b = new BackGround();
                b.execute(Name, Password);

            }
        });
    }

    class BackGround extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String name = params[0];
            String password = params[1];
            String data="";
            int tmp;

            try {
                URL url = new URL("http://192.168.0.12/ProjetoNewWebService/Login.php");
                String urlParams = "name="+name+"&password="+password;

                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                OutputStream os = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                os.write(urlParams.getBytes());
                os.flush();
                os.close();

                InputStream is = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                while((tmp=is.read())!=-1){
                    data+= (char)tmp;
                }

                is.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();

                return data;
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return "Exception: "+e.getMessage();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return "Exception: "+e.getMessage();
            }
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            String err=null;


            try {
                JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(s);
                JSONObject dados = jo.getJSONObject("usuario");
                codAlu    = dados.getString("codAlu");
                nomeAlu   = dados.getString("nomeAlu");
                emailAlu  = dados.getString("emailAlu");
                foneAlu   = dados.getString("foneAlu");

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                err = "Exception: "+e.getMessage();

            }

            //Toast.makeText(TelaLogin.this, s,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent in = new Intent(Telalogin.this,Teladisciplinas.class);
            in.putExtra("codAlu",codAlu);
            in.putExtra("nomeAlu",nomeAlu);
            in.putExtra("emailAlu",emailAlu);
            in.putExtra("foneAlu",foneAlu);
            startActivity(in);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: no erro está aparecendo oque? no logcat do android stúdio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A princípio basta fazer uma validação para verificar se possui caracteres digitados nos campos `name` e `password`. Exemplo:

```
Name = name.getText().toString();
Password = password.getText().toString();

if(Name.length()>0  && Password.length()>0){              

    BackGround b = new BackGround();
    b.execute(Name, Password);

 } else {

    Toast.makeText(this, "Preencha todos os campos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Veja outras ideias:

- [Como testar se um EditText está vazio?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/86544/como-testar-se-um-edittext-est%C3%A1-vazio)
- [Verificar se EditText está vazio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/146042/verificar-se-edittext-est%C3%A1-vazio).
- [Validando o EditText de Maneira Elegante no Android](http://robsonfagundes.blogspot.com.br/2015/06/validacao-elegante-edittext-no-android.html)
- [Android: How can I validate EditText input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763022/android-how-can-i-validate-edittext-input)

Para a segunda situação, no qual está inserindo uma validação incorreta, você deve verificar o retorno dentro do `onPostExecute`. Seu `Intent` deve estar  dentro de uma condição de sucesso ou erro ao logar. Veja abaixo um exemplo. Caso sua `String s` não for um `JSONObject`, isso lhe dará um `JSONException`.

Exemplo:

```
 @Override
 protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
    String err=null;

     try {
            JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(s);
            JSONObject dados = jo.getJSONObject("usuario");
            codAlu    = dados.getString("codAlu");
            nomeAlu   = dados.getString("nomeAlu");
            emailAlu  = dados.getString("emailAlu");
            foneAlu   = dados.getString("foneAlu");

            //Toast.makeText(TelaLogin.this, s,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent in = new Intent(Telalogin.this,Teladisciplinas.class);
            in.putExtra("codAlu",codAlu);
            in.putExtra("nomeAlu",nomeAlu);
            in.putExtra("emailAlu",emailAlu);
            in.putExtra("foneAlu",foneAlu);
            startActivity(in);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            err = "Exception: "+e.getMessage();

        }
 }
```

Comment: Obrigado vou tentar e depois posto o resultado

Comment: Funcionou a parte de verificar se os campos estão vazios, agora a parte de digitar dados incorretos não apresenta erro, simplesmente ele entra na aplicação como se os dados fosse validos.

Comment: @RafaelJacinto eu editei a resposta.

Comment: Show de bola funcionou perfeito muito obrigado.

Comment: @RafaelJacinto legal que funcionou. Se quiser validar a resposta, fique a vontade. =D